# Where can I find the source code for EVP_aes_256_cbc?

Tags: linux, encryption, openssl

I need the source code of the OpenSSL API functions for EVP encryption, like `EVP_aes_256_cbc`.  After much searching, all I could find were the headers of the functions in `openssl/evp.h`, but no source code in a `.c` file.

Where can I find the source code?

Comment: What version of OpenSSL?  In the `0.9.8` series, the function was defined by a macro which is why you can't find the symbol by searching.  I'm guessing you don't care about the implementation of the EVP wrapper `EVP_aes_256_cbc`, but instead you want the code to the AES implementation.  In that case, it's implemented in assembly language.  See `crypto/aes/asm`.  There are a series of perl scripts that generate the asm.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find the final CBC mode implementation in [`cbc128.c`](http://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/openssl/1.0.1c/cbc128_8c_source.html) and AES itself in [`AES.c`](http://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/openssl/1.0.1c/aes__cbc_8c_source.html). Mind that the EVP are high level functions that could use an engine - for instance using a hardware module (HSM) - or AES-NI CPU instructions instead. Searching for a single source file is therefore bunk.

Answer (score -2):

> I need the source code of openssl api functions evp encription... "EVP_AES_256_CBC"...

There is no function `EVP_AES_256_CBC`:

```
$ cd openssl-1.0.1g
$ grep -R EVP_AES_256_CBC *
$
```

So searching for it should turn up no results.

---

> where can I find the source code

As user3553031 pointed out, you can get the source code for OpenSSL at [OpenSSL: Source, Tarballs](https://www.openssl.org/source/).

---

What do you really want?

Comment: Add a `-i` to your grep and you'll get results.

Comment: @indiv - that's not what the OP asked for.

Comment: OK well let's continue punishing him for a poorly worded question instead of helping.  The reason I am sympathetic to the question is because it's not as much of a straightforward answer as you might guess.

Comment: @indiv - he's not being punished. (Or at least not by me. I did not cast a close vote; and I did not down vote him). He does need to state what he wants. That's his obligation to the community.